# Is there a way to convert UnsafeMutablePointer<String> to UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?

Tags: arrays, swift

**Please read EDIT before progressing**

In Swift, I have been messing around with UnsafeMutablePointer's and I have done many examples such as

```
var char: [String] = ["0","281411","-78","521074","-3","344657","132","347776","-93","25","44"]
let pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8> = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: char)
```

But everytime I run it gives me the following error

```
Cannot assign value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<String>' to type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>'
```

So does this mean that UnsafeMutablePointer cannot be converted into UnsafeMutablePointer?

Any advice to guide me in the right direction will be helpful. Thank You in advance.

**EDIT:**
Hello everyone, let me clarify that the var char: [String] is wrong. Matt gave an excellent explanation on how a string can go into UnsafeMutablePointer < Int8 >. You can input a string such as "some argument" into UnsafeMutablePointer < Int8 >. The way I did it is wrong so follow matt's explanation.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem to me. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you think that you need an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`?

Comment: Hello, so my the program I am working on requires me to turn an input(which is a string) to an UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>. I can turn a string such as this "0,281411,-78,521074,-3,344657,132,347776,-93,25,44" into an UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>. However, I was just wondering if an array such as the one I put ontop was possible to turn into an UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>

Comment: What on earth do you want to do with that pointer? Find a way to crash the app? Because if you somehow could convince the compiler to allow this, crashing the app is the best possible thing you could achieve.

Comment: Trust me, if it was my project I would not use it at all. Unfortunately, I have not other choice.

Comment: The thing is, `"0,281411,-78,521074,-3,344657,132,347776,-93,25,44"` is _not_ what you created in the first line. That is a String. What you made is a `[String]` which is a very different animal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C string is an `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<Int8>`. There are ways to derive the C string from a Swift string, and there you are.

To demonstrate, I'll start with an Objective-C method that takes an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`. Here is the interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Thing : NSObject

- (void) passMeACString: (nonnull char[]) s;

@end
```

Here is the implementation; it just prints the received C string, so we know we got one:

```
#import "Thing.h"

@implementation Thing

- (void) passMeACString: (nonnull char[]) s {
    NSLog(@"%s", s);
}

@end
```

Now, if you look at the generated interface, you'll see this:

```
open class Thing : NSObject {
    open func passMeACString(_ s: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>)
}
```

So, you see? It takes an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>`. Now I'll make one in Swift:

```
    let s = "0,281411,-78,521074,-3,344657,132,347776,-93,25,44"
    var arr = s.cString(using: .utf8)!
    let t = Thing()
    t.passMeACString(&arr)
```

Result: `0,281411,-78,521074,-3,344657,132,347776,-93,25,44` is printed in the log. It worked.

Comment: Hey matt! This is 100% what I was looking for. I'm sorry if I my question was confusing with the [String]. I'm still pretty new and learning. I'll be updating my questions so that if anybody finds this question it will be more clear. Thank You!